# Getting my SOAP application to work

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am making a start on SOAP but can't get past the first hurdle of authenticating myself...

Here is my code...

```
$login = array(
    'loginWebRequest'   =>  array(
        'Username'  =>  'myuser',
        'Password'  =>  'mypass'
    )
);

$url = 'https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($url);

$result = $client->Login('Login',$login);
print_r($result);
```

I hope someone can see a mistake I have obviously made!

```
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```

tells me this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => LoginResponse Login(Login $parameters)
    [1] => LogoutResponse Logout(Logout $parameters)
)
```

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$options = array(
    "trace" => 1,
    "exception" => 1
    );

$login = array(
    'loginWebRequest'   =>  array(
        'Username'  =>  'myuser',
        'Password'  =>  'mypass'
    )
);

$url = 'https://qa-api.ukmail.com/Services/UKMAuthenticationServices/UKMAuthenticationService.svc?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($url,$options);

$result = $client->call('Login',$login);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($client->__getLastRequest());
echo "<hr />";
print_r($result);
```

*I recomend the use of **soapui** before any code, is importante to test de wsdl functions and permissions. In SOAPUI you can do a call for login function and it is more fast and easy  to check for example login and password information.*